# VT-x error while running Kali Linux ovf on Virtual Box in 32-bit Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtualization, kali-linux

I have successfully run Ubuntu on my computer with an older version of VBox in Windows 7.

I updated VBox, and downloaded and imported a Kali Linux 2017 i686 .ovf file. But then I got an error after which I installed the extension pack. Now I'm getting a different VT-x error.

If it helps, the Acceleration reads : PAE/NX, KVM paravirtualization. The acceleration tab in settings is disabled.

> Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Kali-Linux-2017.1-vbox-i686.
>
> VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX).
>
> Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
>   Component: ConsoleWrap
>   Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

Comment: What error? Paste the exact error message here.

Comment: Do you use Hyper-V in Windows too? http://druss.co/2015/06/fix-vt-x-is-not-available-verr_vmx_no_vmx-in-virtualbox/ suggests it might be a cause of the error...

Comment: @BigChris Will enabling Hyper-V and/or Virtualization affect my computer in any other way? No negatives right?

Comment: Hyper-V is Microsoft's virtual machine technology but it's a built-in feature that needs to be enabled and would need your VT-x enabling in BIOS etc. before you could use it properly. The reason I ask is that an online resource seems to suggest it may cause the error you're experiencing - along with whether you've actually enabled VT-x in your BIOS :)

Comment: I downloaded Speccy and found out that my system does not support virtualization. Thanks for all your help, though!

Answer (score 0):

I would follow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482223/vt-x-is-not-available-when-i-start-my-virtual-machine

That error is more pointing to that your computers bios doesn't have virtualization enabled. That option isn't available on all CPU's.

Take a look into bios and verify that virtualization is enabled, if you can't find the option, verify that your CPU has the ability.

Most follow a VT- enable/disabled option, generally under CPU settings in bios.

Comment: But the OP states at the start he could run Ubuntu before he upgraded VBox... might have been prudent to ask if the user has enabled VT-x rather than assuming it's off...

Comment: @BigChris He did say that, but most of the time it's disabled. Maybe a firmware or update he did installed disabled it. The only other option I see is that he has Hyper V enabled, and according to http://druss.co/2015/06/fix-vt-x-is-not-available-verr_vmx_no_vmx-in-virtualbox/ can cause same warning.

Comment: Lol which I've already asked the OP under the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Fix: vt-x is not available (verr_vmx_no_vmx) - Appuals.com

There are three most common reasons for this error:

1. Your CPU doesn’t support VT-x or AMD-V virtualization
2. VT-x or AMD-V is not enabled in BIOS (UEFI)
3. You have Hyper-V virtualization enabled in Windows

Solution 1: Enable VT-x in BIOS

Restart your computer
Load into BIOS (press Del, F2, Esc key. Depends on motherboard)
Find Virtualization setting and enabled it. It might look different in you system, but here are some examples:

Solution 2

Open Control Panel
Go to Program section -> Turn Windows features on or off
Disable Hyper-V